# Verify the change of background color of the Textfield

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

How can I verify if the TextField changed its background color after an action is commited or the form is to be submitted?

Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't provide more help if you don't provide any code. But here's demo you can have a look. Basically, you can get all css values by [WebElement.getCssValue method](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#getCssValue%28java.lang.String%29).

http://jsfiddle.net/RuuYs/

```
<input id="txtTest" />
<button id="submit" onclick="document.getElementById('txtTest').style.background = 'orange';">Submit</button>
```

```java
WebElement btnSubmit = drvier.findElement(By.id("submit"));
btnSubmit.click();

WebElement txtTest = drvier.findElement(By.id("txtTest"));
string color = txtTest.getCssValue("background-color");
// color should be "orange" in this case
```